# find List where value == x

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am trying to get a list of all users where the access level is between 0 and 10. The developer users have am higher access level, because they should be able change very critical data.

The current version returns all users.

```
List<UserType> userList = UserType.find.all();
```

Is it possible to do like that:

```
select *
from user
where access_level >= 0
  and
  access_level <=10
;
```

The comparision value is:

```
UserType.getAccessLevel
```

The table is called 'acces_level' in the database.

Comment: Seeing as we know nothing of your code. Maybe yes, and maybe no.

Comment: It's possible to do it like that (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) but if you're a beginner it's probably easier to foreach your list and perform the comparison in the loops body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at home therefore I'm not able to test it but I'm sure you will need **ge()**

```
List<UserType> userList = UserType.find.where().ge("access_level", 10).findList();
```

I think it's a combination of [Junction](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/Junction.html) and [greater than equals to](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/Expr.html#ge-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick glance at [the JPA examples for Playframework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/jpa), it seems that this is perfectly within the realm of possibility.

To express it, you'd need to do something like this:

```
List<UserType> userList = UserType.find("access_level >= 0 AND access_level < 10");
```

Comment: Sorry but that dont work  I got an exception    cannot find symbol symbol: method find(java.lang.String) location: class models.PinRoomUser.UserType

Answer (score 0):

This is a version witch works, but I want to know how it works with the find Method.

```
for(int i = 0; i< userList.size(); i++){
    if(userList.get(i).getAccessLevel() > 10){
        userList.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```